# Create a 3D array from table value

Tags: array

I need to plot the field lines of a 3D vector (Vx, Vy, Vz) of which I have the 3 components at each point of a given 3D grid. One way is to use FLOW3. However, in order to use FLOW3 I need to have the vector in a form of 3D array, and I don't have it. Instead I have a table of six columns in the form X,Y,Z,Vx,Vy,Vz: at each row I have the spatial position (X,Y,Z) and the three components of the vector (Vx,Vy,Vz) at that position. Can REFORM or MAKE_ARRAY do what I need? I can't find a simple way to do it.

Comment: What GIS software (or python library?) are you using?

Comment: Not sure about the question on GIS software. The file was produced with another code. I use IDL 8.5.1.